# Entity Framework Custom Convention Order

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

According to [the custom convention spec](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions) for Entity Framework 6 the last convention wins.  I'm seeing the opposite behavior.  If I use these conventions:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
  .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<UseMaxLengthAttribute>() != null)
  .Configure(c => c.HasMaxLength(int.MaxValue));

// by default, allows nvarchar columns to be indexed (900 byte max)
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(c => c.HasMaxLength(450));
```

then in my migration all `string` columns are `nvarchar(450)` unless the property has a `[UseMaxLength]` attribute.

If I switch the order (putting the default of `HasMaxLength(450)` before the attribute based convention), then all string columns have length of 450, ignoring the custom attribute.  This seems to be opposite of what the spec states (that the last applied convention wins).

Is this a bug, or did I misunderstand the spec?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug that is still present in rc1 but is fixed in nightly builds and will be fixed in release.  For more information on nightly builds check out this page: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Nightly%20Builds you can also read and file bugs for Entity Framework at https://entityframework.codeplex.com/